# PHP how to get the original password after hashed?

Tags: php, hash, passwords

I used `password_hash()` to hash my password, and `password_verify()` for login with my password.

However, `password_verify()` just for boolean the hashed password and the original password.

How can I get the original password that after it has been hashed? Because I want to see my password before I edit it.

my current hashed code:

```
$password = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_BCRYPT, array('cost' => 12));
```

Comment: Hashing is _one-way._ That's the whole point of it. _No one_ is supposed to be able to see the original password after it's hashed.

Comment: You will need a supercomputer for that. Even supercomputer will take years to crack the original password chars.

Comment: That's the beauty of password_hash. It's one way!

Comment: If there password is a usual password as found on a frequent password list the chances are good it can be recovered. That is why a CPU time consuming hashing method must be used such as PBKFD2, Argon2 and for PHP `password_hash` and `password_verify`.

Answer (score 3):

You will not be able to see the original password after it has been hashed. We dont edit a password, we replace them with new ones.

Comment: All Right! I think I should do this way. Thank You for let me know there is no approach to get the original password.